Sign in with Solana - am I getting blocked by wallets/blowfish?
I implemented a basic authentication system in my dapp, mostly following the steps outlined here: https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/dapps/how-to-authenticate-users-with-a-solana-wallet
This worked fine, but I needed to add a workaround for Ledger users that don't have access to the "signMessage" method in their wallet adapter. So I used signTransaction instead and verify the payload.
Once my dapp was deployed, the signMessage method is never available, but I think it was usable for at least some time. I know that this method has potential for abuse, has my app been somehow blocked/limited by all the wallets or blowfish?
I got my idea on how to allow Ledger users to sign in from magic eden, so I don't understand why it wouldn't work for me.
To be clear, the sign in system for Ledger users works fine in local development, it just doesn't work once the app is deployed.
